# Java poker deck all same cards

Tags: java

I've created a deck `Card[52] theDeck` and it seems to only contain Kings of Spades. I don't think anything wrong with the constructor, but I'm new to java, so I might be wrong...
Here's the deck constructor:

```
public class Deck {

private Card[] theDeck; 
private int top; 
// add more instance variables if needed

public Deck(){
    theDeck = new Card[52];
    for(int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
    {
        for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++)
            {

                theDeck[i] = new Card(s,v);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

It should be creating 52 distinct Card objects, but when I print it, every card is Card(4,13) -- King of Spades.

Here's the Card constructor just in case:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card>
{

private int suit; 
private int value; 

public Card(int s, int v)
{ //constructor of an object Card
    suit = s;
    value = v;
    //make a card with suit s and value v
}
```

Comment: I would use a List in place of array anyways. So much more convenient to work with afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got three loops, and your *inner* loop goes through the whole range of the deck - and assigns a card to it which doesn't depend on the index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theDeck.length; i++)
{
    theDeck[i] = new Card(s,v);
}
```

So for each value of `s` and `v` you're overwriting the whole deck with the same card. The final card you create is the king of spades, hence the problem.

I suspect you don't want that inner loop at all - instead, work out the index to use based on `s` and `v`:

```
for (int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
{
    for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
    {
        int index = (s - 1) * 13 + (v - 1);
        theDeck[index] = new Card(s, v);
    }
}
```

Or keep a separate `index` variable and just increment that:

```
int index = 0;
for (int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
{
    for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
    {
        theDeck[index] = new Card(s, v);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much--it worked. I still don't understand why it was making all of them King of Spades...

Comment: @user3505003: Then you should think carefully about it before moving on - read my answer again, particularly the first part. Then go over your original code with a debugger, taking careful note of exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your last loop was unnecessary,
try this

```
public Deck(){
    theDeck = new Card[52];
    int i=0;
    for(int s = 1; s <= 4; s++)
    {
        for (int v = 1; v <= 13; v++)
        {
            theDeck[i++] = new Card(s,v);

        }
    }   
}
```