# Preventing IndexOutOfBoundsException on while loop [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I am making a card game and it works well except I cannot get to the bottom of the deck without running into an IndexOutOfBoundsException error at some point. I have an array of numbers between 1 and 52 that are randomized and I use that to choose what index to call from the arrayList of cards I have. Since the deck is an ArrayList I can remove each card after each loop easily. But I cannot remove the number from the random number array and so as the list of cards gets smaller, the bigger chance of calling an index that is too high I get. Can't figure out a way around it. I have tried using an if statement to change the value of the the random number to something less than the max length of the arrayList but still get the error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Welcome to War! Press enter to begin."); //User prompt
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner init
    String[] suit = {" of Diamonds", " of Spades", " of Hearts", " of Clubs"};//Array for suits
    String[] faces = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};//Array for faces
    String[] deck = new String[52]; //Deck size setup
    boolean deckComplete = false;//Boolean for deck being finished
    int[] random = new int[52];//Array for all numbers between 0 and the number of cards in the deck multiplied by number of decks
    ArrayList<Integer> random1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int playerOneTotal = 0;
    int playerTwoTotal = 0;



    for (int x = 0; x<random.length; x++) {
        random[x] = x;
    }//Content setup for random array

    Random rndNum = new Random();//Random init

    int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

            deck[i] = faces[i % 13] + suit[i % 4];
        }//Deck of cards setup



    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(deck));//Changing Array with card contents into an ArrayList

    while (deckComplete == false) {         //While loop for dealing cards


        for (int j = deck.length; j >= 1; j--) {


           // System.out.println("Hit enter to be dealt a card!");    
            String readString = scanner.nextLine(); //Set variable "readString" to user input
            int randomNumber = rndNum.nextInt(j);
            int randomNumberTwo = rndNum.nextInt(j);


            if (readString.equals("")) {        //If user input equals "enter"...

                 if (randomNumber >= arrayList.size()) {
                    randomNumber = arrayList.size() - 1;
                }

                if (randomNumberTwo == arrayList.size()) {
                    randomNumberTwo = arrayList.size() - 1;
                }


                  int playerOne = random[randomNumber];
                  int playerTwo = random[randomNumberTwo];
                  int playerOneScore = 0;
                  int playerTwoScore = 0;


                  System.out.println("Player One Draws a: " + arrayList.get(random[randomNumber])); //Print out card
                  arrayList.remove(random[randomNumber]); //Remove card from deck
                  System.out.println("Player Two Draws a: " + arrayList.get(random[randomNumberTwo])); //Print out card
                  arrayList.remove(random[randomNumberTwo]); //Remove card from deck


                  playerOneTotal = playerOneTotal + playerOneScore;
                  playerTwoTotal = playerTwoTotal + playerTwoScore;

                  if (playerOneTotal > playerTwoTotal) {
                      System.out.println("Player One Wins this round! Current Score - Player One: " + playerOneTotal + " Player Two: " + playerTwoTotal);
                  }else if (playerOneTotal < playerTwoTotal) {
                      System.out.println("Player Two Wins this round! Current Score - Player One: " + playerOneTotal + " Player Two: " + playerTwoTotal);
                  }else if (playerOneTotal == playerTwoTotal) {

                  }


                   if (j == 1) {    //If program gets to last card...
                       deckComplete = true; //Set desk complete to true

                       System.out.println(arrayList.get(random[randomNumber])); //Print last card
                       arrayList.remove(random[randomNumber]); //Remove last card
                       System.out.println("You are out of cards!"); //Print "You are out of cards"
                       break; //Stop loop
                   }  
               }



       }
```

Is there any method besides trying (below) that would get me the right outcome?

```
if (randomNumber >= arrayList.size()) {
                    randomNumber = arrayList.size() - 1;
                }

                if (randomNumberTwo == arrayList.size()) {
                    randomNumberTwo = arrayList.size() - 1;
                }
```

Edit: Here is the exact error message.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 33, Size: 23
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at Game.main(Game.java:72)`

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of the exception you get.

Comment: @LittleSanti Sorry. Updated.

Comment: Maybe setting the nexInt parameter to the minimum of `j` and the list size would be enough? You can use Math.min

Comment: @sergioFC Thanks for the response. Can you clarify that a little? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Me bad, I think I am not getting the problem

Comment: @Andreas Guess I was thinking too hard on that one. Now that I do the math again, I can see that it indeed works fine. I'll remove my previous comment to avoid any misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

If I read correctly, you're selecting a random card from the `ArrayList` on every turn. You can make your life a lot easier by shuffling the entire `ArrayList` at the start of the game (similar to how you would shuffle a deck in real life). Then you can simply remove the first (or last) element of the list without having to worry about an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To shuffle the entire deck, use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29):

```
Collections.shuffle(fileList, new Random());
```

Taking the top card from the deck:

```
arrayList.remove(0);
```

Comment: I will try to implement this as it does look a lot more clean than the current method I was using to achieve this. I do believe I would still be left with the issue of not being able to increment the random numbers downward in relation to the amount of elements in the deck. My main issue is that I constantly run into calling index 43 or so when there are only 35 elements left in the deck.

Comment: I think the problem is in the two `arrayList.remove` statements. Once you remove the first element, the list is shorter. When you remove the second element, t's possible the index for this second element is no longer valid. For example, the list has length 36. Random number 1 is 13, random number 2 is 35. Remove element at index 13 => list length is 35. Remove element at index 35 => `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. To bypass this, first do a `String card = arrayList.get(i)` for both random numbers and then do `arrayList.remove(card)`. This ensures you remove the actual card, regardless of index.

Answer (score 1):

You have `deck` which is the full list of 52 cards, in order, as you have.

You create `arrayList` as a copy of that, as you did, except you rename it `stack` (or `cardStack`), then:

- Shuffle the `stack` using [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29)
- Take cards from `stack` using `remove(stack.size()-1)` (or `remove(0)`, but that's slower).

Better yet, use [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) instead of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), because it can be used as a LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stack. In your case, you would then use [`stack.pop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#pop%28%29) to take a card.

---

**Followup**

In order for the game to work, a card must be more than just the text "Ace of Spade". You need to know that it's an Ace, and that it's a Spade, so you need a class, e.g. named `Card`, with two fields: `suit` and `face`. The `toString()` method of that class would then return "Ace of Spade".

Also note that you'll never access the `cardStack` with an index, unless you want to cheat. The only action allowed after the stack is shuffled is `pop()`, to take the card at the top of the stack.

Your overall loop will look something like this:

```
// Build deck
...

// Create shuffled stack
Deque<Card> cardStack = new ArrayDeque<>(Arrays.asList(deck));
Collections.shuffle(cardStack, rndNum);

// Play game
while (! cardStack.isEmpty()) {
    Card player1card = cardStack.pop();
    Card player2card = cardStack.pop();

    // do you stuff here
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the solution you are saying but I think I would still be left with the issue of calling an index that is higher than the amount of elements in `deck`. Is there any way to remove numbers as well as removing the cards so that I don't end up calling for index 43 while the ArrayList size is 38?

Comment: Thanks for this. I see how this method is better. I have already written out how to do the program the way I've done it and I can't seem to figure out how to build the deck based on using a separate card class. Sorry I'm still a beginner at this. Could you provide some guidance?

Comment: See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904482/java-poker-deck-all-same-cards